# Cannot see the end part of post in my recyclerview completely

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is the feed where I used recyclerview in home fragment to show posts but in it, I can't see the last post completely and if I add any textview below that still can't view it.

[image: Here is the image]
As shown in the image I can't see the like comment and share button of the last post

I tried putting the textview inside the swiperefreshlayout and out of it but still not working here is the code for fragment and activity:

Fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_grey">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/pullToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/spppp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pullToRefresh"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/homeend"
        android:layout_below="@id/spppp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_post_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.954"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.88"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is in the activity layout. Your fragment takes up the width and height of the activity, but you're also displaying a bottom navigation view at the bottom, it might be hiding part of the fragment.

Try setting your fragment to fill up the activity, but also be on top of the bottom navigation bar. You're currently setting the fragment's height to `match_parent`, which is making its `layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"` useless.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks , setting fragment layout height="0dp" solved the issue